# Никак не могу заставить программу находить косинус

Tags: c#

Нужно написать программу со статистическим методом для вычисления косинуса, используя формулу Cos(x) = 1-(x^2)/2! + (x^4)/4! - (x^6)/6!...+((-1)^n)*(x^2n))/(2n)!
Однако выдаёт очень большие числа после, если ввожу x >= 3.
Уже детально просматривал формулы, но ошибок не нашёл. Помогите,пожалуйста....

```
 class Maths
     {
         // Метод вычисления факториала
         public static int Fact(int x)
         {
             int res = 1;
             for (int i = x; i >= 2; i--)
             {
                 res *= i;
             }
             return res;
         }

         public static double Ch;

         // Метод вычисления косинуса
         public static double Cos( double Ch)
         {
             double Otv = 0;

             for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                  Otv += Math.Pow((-1),i) * Math.Pow(Ch, 2* i )/Maths.Fact(2 * i);
                 
                     }
             Otv = 1 - Otv;
             return Otv;
         }
     }
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
             double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) ;
             x = Maths.Cos(x);
             Console.WriteLine("Cos = " + x);

         }
```

Comment: Используйте для больших чисел double, например.

Comment: Жаль что вы результаты тестов не показали - вопрос ваш - не полный. Как раз на тестах было бы видно что так а что не так. Вот я и вспомнил учёбу. Cos задаётся от -pi до pi, поэтому вам не нужно искать его для чисел свыше 3,14. Практичнски диапазона от 0 до pi вполне достаточно что бы составить полную таблицу. Во вторых вам в ответе, который вы заминусовали, показали график значений вашей функции при x в пределах примерно от -10 до +10 чего вполне достаточно. Тесты можно было бы сопоставить с графиками. Желательно вспомнить определение косинуса и его свойства, например периодичность. Удачи.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, в инструкции к работе есть строчка - метод хорошо работает для малых чисел.

Comment: @nick_n_a ,Спасибо, ответы я только увидел и понял свою проблему, минусов я, вроде,не кидал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
     public static double Fact(int x)
     {
         double res = 1;
         for (int i = x; i >= 2; i--)
         {
             res *= i;
         }
         return res;
     }
```

Comment: @nick_n_a Вероятно, у ТС не хватает членов в разложении. Хотя для `x = 3` и шести членов должно хватать.

Comment: По-моему всё просто. Я уже понял что это график косинуса и это значит что всё у ТС работает. Ага, ему сказали проверить при допустим 10, а он не знает что при 3 у него уже программа работает. Для 10 ему программа сказала Overflow, и просто ТС не знает что дальше делать и минусует ваш ответ, т.к. не понял зачем ему график показали. Надо добавить что это график который выдаст его программа, если подшаманить немного)

Comment: А ещё хорошо бы SO читать преподам))))